# concatenate prefix in the function name with macro?

Tags: c, macros

I want to concatenate some macro in the beginning of function name:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PFX mypfx

int PFX##_call() {
    printf("teeeeeeeeest");
}

int main(void)
{
    mypfxcall();
}
```

The above code return error in compilation.

How to add prefix with macro in the function name?

Comment: Why? Really, it just seems like an exercise in obfuscation.

Comment: what do you actually want to achieve? smells like [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: macros like this are a great way to have people never want to use or maintain your code

Comment: please choose one lanuguage, in c++ there are 1 maybe 2 use cases for macros (yours is not one of them), in c I dont know

Comment: What's the point? So you can write `PFX_myfunc()` instead of `mypfx_myfunc()`? I don't see the point.

Comment: Why is this question filled by useless comments to it? "obfuscation", "xy problem", "use C++ and don't use macros", and "what's the point"? There is a perfect point - you need to link bunch of libraries statically and one of them actually appears twice in dependency list, sometimes different versions of it. So you may really want to link two of them via prefixing hack.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you would want to do this (maybe because you want to "emulate" namespaces), but assuming you're in C, you can achieve it with the following code.

```
#define concat2(X, Y) X ## Y
#define concat(X, Y) concat2(X, Y)
#define pfx(x) concat(pfx_, x)
```

Usage:

```
int pfx(sum)(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", pfx(sum)(5,4));
}
```

Note: if you want to use more macro processing power (i don't know if it's you case) you should visit [P99](https://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/)

Answer (score 3):

The `##` operator only allows you to concatenate two strings inside another macro definition.

But this:

```
int PFX##_call()
```

is not a macro definition, therefor it will expand to this which is invalid C:

```
int mypfx##_call()
```

Example of valid usage:

```
#define FOO 1
#define BAR 2
#define FB FOO##BAR    // FB will expand to FOOBAR
                       // independently of the macros FOO and BAR

#define BF FOO BAR     // BF will expand to 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a `namespace` instead:

```
namespace mypfx
{
    int call() {
         printf("teeeeeeeeest");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    mypfx::call();
}
```

Comment: This is only valid for C++.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yet another reason to always prefer C++ over C! :)

Comment: @PaulEvans this is not a valid comment and anwser at all. Sometimes you cannot choose and you are bounded by other constaints. You may work with not only your projects but integrating other code as well.

Comment: @AntonBreusov The word "prefer" implies "given a choice".